# SQL fast in PSQL, very slow using MS.NET driver

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

There's [thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/002f01c89a42%241a117590%244e3460b0%24%40com) with exact same title and problem, but with no answer, NPGSQL driver takes very long time to execute queries, but other language drivers or terminal works fine.

From what I've found, it's related to parameter sniffing in other SQL databases, but I could not find much for Postgres.

I'm running UPDATE statement, so it doesn't return many rows.

.NET Core 3.0, NPGSQL 4.1.1, PostgreSQL 10.9 (Ubuntu)

Comment: See if setting `cursor_tuple_fraction` to 1.0 makes a difference. Are there many result rows?

Comment: no, it doesn't make difference, I'm running UPDATE command, so just 1 result row

Comment: Is this a prepared statement in PostgresSQL? Are PL/pgSQL functions involved? You might want to turn on statement logging in PostgreSQL to know for sure.

Comment: It might not return any rows, but how many rows does it update?  Can you turn set log_statement='all' so you can see exactly how it is interacting with the server?